# How to select element in pop up message using webdriver?

Tags: java, webdriver

i have a web page where i can create a document.
When i save the document i have a message like "Document successfully saved"

The message appears only for 3 seconds.
How can i find the element with webdriver to check the message has been displayed during my test.

In the html code, i tried to catch the code for this message, it appears for 3 seconds and the disappaeared.

The code is here:

```
<div class="alert alert-success top center alert-notify alert-icon>
Document successfully saved.
<span class="Close"></span>
```

I tried this without success:

```
try {
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
message = alert.getText();
alert.accept();
} catch (Exception e) {
message = null;
}
System.out.println("message"+message);
return message;
}
```

then i tried this without success too:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("alert alert-success top center alert-notify")).isDisplayed();             
Thread.sleep(3000);              
System.out.println(" Alert message is displayed");
```

Can anyone help me please, i don't know how to handle with

Answer (score 0):

your second try is the right way to detect the message, but your have to try for 3 seconds to find the element.
It should look like this

```
while (!elementFound || stillWithin3Seconds){
  elementFound = findAlertByClassName()
}
assetTrue(elementFound)
```

You have to look all the time. In your code you are sleeping. When the dialog appears in this time, you won't notice it.

Comment: Just one more: at first. Leave your message open and check if the findElement works properly.

Comment: Thank you but i cannot find the element in the message by className, with which method do you find the element?

Comment: maybe it's because alert-icon is missimgmin the selector. Mabemtry to set an id to the div-element and try to select this.

Comment: The alrt message is not like a pop up window where i have to click OK or Cancel, the message appears and disappears asap.

Comment: I know, however can you change the code that way, that it stays and you can play around with it? or get the html just to build the test.

Comment: i tried to fetch the html code during hte alert message by examining the alert and i got the above html code in my question

Comment: finally i found the element by xpath but it's not a good solution, xpath can fall anything and my code will be broken